# Jenkins Active Choice Parameter in Multibranch pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I would like to use the Active Choice Parameter in Jenkins for the following purpose: 
My project developers want to run a Jenkins build for different branches, which basically shouts "Multibranch"!! The thing is, that the developers want to get a notification in the Job's page (where you hit BUILD) if the latest commit in the repo is not tagged.

I can easily do this if I let the developer to choose the branch he wants to build via a parameter, such as Git Parameter, and then reference the chosen value with Active Choice Reference Parameter.

The question is, if I want to use Multibranch Pipeline, is there a way to know in the Active Choice Parameter script which branch was chosen?? I actually doubt there is such possibility but I thought I'll ask here before I think of another solution..

Comment: I would also desperately need this. I also made a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67099711/jenkins-active-choice-reactive-reference-parameter-formatted-html-in-multibranch) about it myself. I tried everything in my power and I have some experience with it, but I could not solve it. I will follow this post. I think I have a workaround for you, but for me, I don't :(

Answer (score 1):

The Active Choices param is really cool, but it's so strange at the same time. And also the documentation is lacking, like really, really bad.

I think I have a workaround for you, but depending on what kind of Active Choice parameter you use, this may or may not work for you. P.S.: this solution is really not elegant.

```
[
    $class: 'ChoiceParameter',
    choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT',
    description: '',
    filterable: true,
    name: 'TestParam',
    description: 'A description.',
    script: [
        $class: 'GroovyScript',
        fallbackScript: [
            classpath: [],
            sandbox: false,
            script: '''
                return ['error']
            '''
        ], 
        script: [
            classpath: [],
            sandbox: false,
            script: '''
                def branchNameRex = ".+?/job/.+?/job/([^/]+)/.*"
                def threadName = Thread.currentThread().toString()
                def branchName = (threadName =~ branchNameRex)[0][1]
                return [branchName]
            '''
        ]
    ]
]
```

So if you are lucky enough to need to use `ChoiceParameter` with `PT_SINGLE_SELECT` and also be in a Multibranch Pipeline Job, this should work.

The reasoning. `Thread.currentThread().toString()` returns the full path of the current job which luckily includes the branch name. With that regex, I only get the branch name, like `feature/something` or `main`.

Sadly for me, I tried it with `DynamicReferenceParameter` and `ET_FORMATTED_HTML` and the `Thread.currentThread().toString()` returns something else.

This may also depend on the version of the plugin, I don't know for sure, but I have done it like this and it worked in that specific case.

### UPDATE

Okay, after a lot of digging, and I played with this myself a lot, I think I have a solution. You need two parameters to make this work.

There is a `FORMATTED_HIDDEN_HTML` parameter type that won't get displayed to the user. We will define this parameter as follows

```
[
    $class: 'DynamicReferenceParameter',
    choiceType: 'ET_FORMATTED_HIDDEN_HTML',
    name: 'BranchName',
    omitValueField: true,
    script: [
        $class: 'GroovyScript',
        fallbackScript: [
            classpath: [],
            sandbox: true,
            script: '''
                return '<p>error</p>'
            '''
        ], 
        script: [
            classpath: [],
            sandbox: true,
            script: """
                return '<input name="value" value="${env.BRANCH_NAME}" type="text">'
            """
        ]
    ]
]
```

There are a couple of important things to note here.

1. the return type must be of type input, otherwise, you won't be able to access its value
2. it needs to have the property `name` set to `value`.

These are described in the [docs](https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/).
3. Note the script's triple-double quotes `"""`. What this does, it uses string interpolation with `${env.BRANCH_NAME}`. This value doesn't exist at first. Only after you press Build it gets populated.

Basically, from the second build onwards this parameter will remain unchanged with the branch name. This is excellent if you have a multibranch pipeline job.

After that, you can use it as a reference parameter in the other reactive parameters.

Thanks to [Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10493338/michael-kemmerzell)'s answer to [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67099711/jenkins-active-choice-reactive-reference-parameter-formatted-html-in-multibranch/67103309?noredirect=1#comment118613842_67103309), I managed to figure this out. I don't know if it suits your needs, but for me it is perfect.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the effort ! I also thought in the direction of somehow get the Job's name from Jenkins classes tree, but I'm not so good at Java so I couldn't figure it out. I'll try it out, although I don't think I'll use it in production since it doesn't seem so stable. If you'll like joining hands in trying to improve the plugin I'll be glad.

Comment: Yup, don't use it in prod. I would love to. I searched how I could help with the plugin development but I didn't find a way.

Comment: I've answered it in more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67099711/jenkins-active-choice-reactive-reference-parameter-formatted-html-in-multibranch/67132858#67132858).

Comment: You mean the value of the parameter will be set once you run the build for the first time, and then it stays populated between builds? That's weird..

Comment: I wouldn't call it weird. This behaviour is also applied to parameters. If you have Jenkinsfile with parameters that must be filled defined in a GitHub and you create a pipeline job, the first run will fail since the params won't be rendered. You will have a Build button and after the first run, it transforms into BuildWithParameters. it's approximately the same thing.