# Jenkins Active Choice Reactive Reference Parameter Formatted HTML in MultiBranch pipeline job get current branch name in script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I am trying for a lot of time to get the **current branch name** in MultibranchPipeline Job **inside** an  Active Choice Reactive Reference Parameter Formatted HTML parameter script block

```
[
    $class: 'DynamicReferenceParameter',
    choiceType: 'ET_FORMATTED_HTML',
    name: 'TestParam',
    omitValueField: true,
    description: 'Test.',
    script: [
        $class: 'GroovyScript',
        fallbackScript: [
            classpath: [],
            sandbox: false,
            script: '''
                return """
                    <p>FallbackScript. Error in main script</p>
                """
            '''
        ], 
        script: [
            classpath: [],
            sandbox: false,
            script: '''
                String branchName = env.BRANCH_NAME
                return """
                    <p>${branchName}</p>
                """
            '''
        ]
    ]
]
```

The thing is that, I believe, the `BRANCH_NAME` param is injected after you press the `Build` button.

I've tried a lot of things, and I mean, A LOT, still I didn't manage to find a way. The `scm` variable doesn't exist as well, I tried to find something with the `jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance` but no luck.

Is it possible? I would love to ask this question on their Github repo, but issues are not allowed to be opened. Also to open an issue on Jenkins you need a Jira account or something. SO is the only place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at Groovy's [string interpolation](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_interpolation).

tl;dr You can access values by using `"""` and `${variable}`

```
script: """
    return <p>${env.BRANCH_NAME}</p>
"""
```

Comment: I know about string interpolation and I used it in my example. Your answer does not work, you have to wrap with quotes the return value. After that, it works, but it comes with a couple of caveats. I don't know if you are familiar with the plugin mentioned. These parameters are reactive and they change or let's say they compute stuff when you press `Build with parameters`. Your example works because what it does, at moment `t`, you press build, and at moment `t + 1`, you will have the value in the script's string. But it is not computed at `t`.

Comment: Besides that, you would have to approve the script's signature every time you create a new branch because the value will change and you will have `<p>foo/bar</p>` or `<p>foo/baz</p>` etc. Although your answer works, it isn't helpful in my scenario. I will wait for another solution and if I don't get one, I will accept yours.

Comment: Okay I understand. The issue sounds more complex than I thought on first sight.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to Michael's answer, I managed to find a way to make this work. There are a lot more to it than meets the eye, but I will get through all details. I also answered this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67090148/jenkins-active-choice-parameter-in-multibranch-pipeline/67099987#67099987).

I make the assumption that the reader is familiar with the [Active Choices plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/). Also, I played with this in a multibranch pipeline job. You might encounter different behaviours with other kinds of jobs.

The parameters sadly don't have access to the environment variables. This is a bit of a limitation which I hope will be fixed/thought of in the future by the plugin's maintainers.

Some environment variables are only populated at build time, like `BRANCH_NAME`. In this case, even if we had access to the env vars we wouldn't have the actual value at hand.

To be able to use the `env.BRANCH_NAME` we need two reactive parameters.

The plugin has a parameter named `FORMATTED_HIDDEN_HTML`. This parameter doesn't get displayed to the user. This is great since we wouldn't want to see in a multibranch pipeline job a parameter with the same name as the branch we are currently on.

To set this parameter, we can write something like this in a Jenkinsfile.

```
[
    $class: 'DynamicReferenceParameter',
    choiceType: 'ET_FORMATTED_HIDDEN_HTML',
    name: 'BranchName',
    omitValueField: true,
    script: [
        $class: 'GroovyScript',
        fallbackScript: [
            classpath: [],
            sandbox: true,
            script: '''
                return '<p>error</p>'
            '''
        ], 
        script: [
            classpath: [],
            sandbox: true,
            script: """
                return '<input name="value" value="${env.BRANCH_NAME}" type="text">'
            """
        ]
    ]
]
```

There are a lot of things to note here.

1. The `sandbox` property is set to `true`. If you don't do that, you would need to accept the script in the `ScriptApproval` menu in Jenkins.
2. We use triple-double quotes when we define the `script` property.

```
script: """
    return '<input name="value" value="${env.BRANCH_NAME}" type="text">'
"""
```

When the job is started for the first time, the `BRANCH_NAME` variable is populated. This results in a string interpolation which gets your script property in the following state:

```
script: """
    return '<input name="value" value="myBranchName" type="text">'
"""
```

If we would've used triple-single quotes, we would get an error like:

> hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: env for class: WorkflowScript

This gets us back to the fact that we don't have access to the environment variables.

What to conclude from this? Well, if we use triple-double quotes, **first** we have a string interpolation, **then** the script is run.

3. The HTML element that **must** be used is `input`. This is explained in the docs if you read it carefully. Not only that but also the `name` property must be set to `value`. This is also explained in the docs.
4. `omitValueField` should be set to `true`, or else you will get a trailing comma in your value. E.g.: `myBranchName,`

Basically, the first time you run the job you get your branch name populated via string interpolation. Only after the second build, you will have the value to use. You will always reference the previous value.

After all that, you can reference this parameter in other `Active Choices` parameter types via `referencedParameters` property.

I desperately needed this because I have a complex use case scenario. I'm making requests to an `Azure Container Registry` to get all the tags for a certain image for a certain **branch**.

This plugin is great, I'm glad it exists. I would've loved a lot more documentation and examples thoguh.

Comment: nice to hear that you figured it out!

Comment: Your reply related to single/double quotes and omitValueField description are help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use 2 DynamicReferenceParameter. Just use this normal one, followed by the other dynamic param.

`extendedChoice( defaultValue: "${env.BRANCH_NAME}", name: "branchName", type: 'PT_HIDDEN', value: "${env.BRANCH_NAME}")`